# JavaScript short way of selecting false on ternary

Tags: javascript

I've just seen this code:

```
let someVar = 'A'
const result = someArray.length === 0 ? false : someVar === 'B'
```

Can I just check for?

```
const result = someArray.length ? someVar === 'B' : false
```

Also, can use a double negation instead of that `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use logical AND with double negation.

```
result = !!someArray.length && someVar === 'B';
```

Comment: And the code is more readable than using a ternary.  +1